# How to overload operator with type synonyms?

Tags: haskell

I want to construct a rule using operator and the definition of rule as below:

```
type Rule a = [Symbol a]
```

and the definition of symbol as :

```
data Symbol a = Empty | End | LangSym a
```

and now to define an operator `<.>` which can apply to four situations as below:

```
(<.>)::Symbol a->Symbol a->Rule a
(<.>)::Rule a->Symbol a->Rule a
(<.>)::Symbol a->Rule a->Rule a
(<.>)::Rule a->Rule a->Rule a
```

Obviously, we need to overload the operator `<.>` using typeclass as

```
class RuleOperator s1 s2 where
    (<.>)::s1 a->s2 a->Rule a
```

It is no problem when instances the typeclass with `Symbol` as

```
instance RuleOperator Symbol Symbol where
    x <.> y = [x, y]
```

but when the instance has `Rule a`, since the `Rule a` is type synonyms, we cannot do that as

```
instance RuleOperator Symbol Rule where
    ....
```

and the restriction is that we cannot change the definition of `Rule a` to

```
newtype Rule a = R [Symbol a]
```

Since other modules has depended on the original definition of `Rule a`.

Any suggestion for implements such operator with overload without change the definition of `Rule` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use a newtype wrapper, you could use a type family for this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

type Rule a = [Symbol a]

data Symbol a = Empty | End | LangSym a

class RuleOperator t1 t2 where
   type Elem t1 t2
   (<.>) :: t1 -> t2 -> Rule (Elem t1 t2)

instance RuleOperator (Symbol a) (Symbol a) where
   type Elem (Symbol a) (Symbol a) = a
   s1 <.> s2 = [s1, s2]

instance RuleOperator (Symbol a) (Rule a) where
   type Elem (Symbol a) (Rule a) = a
   (<.>) = (:)

instance RuleOperator (Rule a) (Symbol a) where
   type Elem (Rule a) (Symbol a) = a
   r <.> s = r ++ [s]

instance RuleOperator (Rule a) (Rule a) where
   type Elem (Rule a) (Rule a) = a
   (<.>) = (++)
```

Make the class take the fully applied type, so that type synonyms are not an issue, and then use the `Elem` type family to recover the `a` argument.

---

Here are two alternative which allow both inside-out and outside-in type inference.  One using type families and constraints:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

type Rule a = [Symbol a]

data Symbol a = Empty | End | LangSym a

class (a ~ Elem t1 t2) => RuleOperator t1 t2 a where
   type Elem t1 t2
   (<.>) :: t1 -> t2 -> Rule (Elem t1 t2)

instance (a ~ b, a ~ c) => RuleOperator (Symbol a) (Symbol b) c where
   type Elem (Symbol a) (Symbol b) = a
   s1 <.> s2 = [s1, s2]

instance (a ~ b, a ~ c) => RuleOperator (Symbol a) (Rule b) c where
   type Elem (Symbol a) (Rule b) = a
   (<.>) = (:)

instance (a ~ b, a ~ c) => RuleOperator (Rule a) (Symbol b) c where
   type Elem (Rule a) (Symbol b) = a
   r <.> s = r ++ [s]

instance (a ~ b, a ~ c) => RuleOperator (Rule a) (Rule b) c where
   type Elem (Rule a) (Rule b) = a
   (<.>) = (++)
```

and another using functional dependencies (which act a bit like type functions/families with constraints):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

type Rule a = [Symbol a]
data Symbol a = Empty | End | LangSym a

class RuleOperator t1 t2 a | t1 -> a, t2 -> a where
  (<.>) :: t1 -> t2 -> Rule a
instance RuleOperator (Symbol a) (Symbol a) a where
   s1 <.> s2 = [s1, s2]
instance RuleOperator (Rule a) (Symbol a) a where
   r <.> s = r ++ [s]
instance RuleOperator (Symbol a) (Rule a) a where
  (<.>) = (:)
instance RuleOperator (Rule a) (Rule a) a where
  (<.>) = (++)
```

A few tests for inference:

```
sym1, sym2 :: Symbol Int
sym1 = undefined
sym2 = undefined

rule :: Rule Int
rule = undefined

testInsideOut = sym1 <.> rule  -- type is inferred

polySym :: Show a => Symbol a
polySym = Empty

polyRule :: Show a => Rule a
polyRule = [Empty]

testOutSideIn :: Rule Int
testOutSideIn = polySym <.> polyRule  -- Show instances are resolved to Int
```

Comment: Problem is that this prevents “outside in” type inference. In practice, this tends to make everything _very_ unwieldy, requiring lots of local type signatures. At any rate you should make it `instance (a~b) => RuleOperator (Rule a) (Symbol b)` etc., then at least the type can be inferred from one argument to the other, but still not from the result to either of the arguments. (This is assuming that the `a` parameter is actually made use of; if it's almost always `()` or something then it'll be fine, but arguably useless.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout True. Please see my last edit, which seems to work. (It could be overcomplicated, though.)

Comment: Looks like it also works to use functional dependencies instead of a type family: `class Foo t1 t2 a | t1 -> a, t2 -> a` with `instance Foo (Symbol a) (Symbol a) a`, etc.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Indeed it does. That is a much simpler way of making inference work.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Doesn't that have the problem leftaroundabout described above? Namely, outside-in does not work? Did you try the tests for inference I wrote above?

Comment: @chi, yes, I tried your tests, and both outside-in and inside-out inference seemed to work fine.

Comment: I've added my alternative as an edit -- if you spot a problem with it, feel free to revert.